# webbrowser dynamic link on phonebook webpage using c#

Tags: c#, url, browser

I'm writing a program using c#. in the last form, i got a button called "phonebook". when i press it, it should open a webbrowser with the url "tel.search.ch" (its a swiss german site ;)). i already studied the url of the website. it is like this:

tel.search.ch/?what=forename+surname&where=livingplace

but when i click the button, it opens the webbrowser but the url is the home site of this website. so the webbrowser navigate to tel.search.ch and not to my defined url. here you can see my code:

Form5 (last form with button):

```
private void btnTel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form6 form6 = new Form6();
            this.Hide();
            form6.Show();
        }
```

Form6 (webbrowser):

```
public partial class Form6 : Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadForm
    {

        public Form6()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string forename;
        public string surname;
        public string address;
        public string postalcode;
        public string livingplace;


        private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://tel.search.ch/?what=" + forename + "+" + surname + "&where=" + livingplace);


//this code is that my program got the value of the textbox from form1 and form2. it is defined in Program.cs
                Program.forenametext = vorname;
                Program.surnametext = nachname;
                Program.livingplacetext = ort;
            }
        }
```

i don't know why the webbrowser navigate to the home-site of this website. has someone an idea?

cheers

Comment: Are you sure that your URL format is correct?  I tried the one you gave and it didn't seem to work.  But playing around with the site's buttons revealed that something like "http://tel.search.ch/?was=john" does work.

Comment: hm yeah i've tested it many times in ie, ff and chrome and it seems to work. only if i run it with the program, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://tel.search.ch/?what=" + forename + "+" + surname + "&where=" + livingplace);
```

Your variables `forename`, `surname` and `livingplace` are not initialized. URL looks like `http://tel.search.ch/?what=+&where=`. So your URL(specially the query string)  is not getting parsed by the site and it redirects to the homepage. You can check it by putting some static value or by initializing these.

Even you are using wrong URL and dont use `+` for `forename + "+" + surname`. This will be :

```
 webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://tel.search.ch/?was="+forename + " " + surname+ "&wo=" + livingplace);
```

Comment: That could be, but I'm guessing all the code isn't being shown.

Comment: oh yeah that's it! i wrote down some random text instead of forename and the website is starting correct. i will look at it. thank you guy! :)

Comment: Yeah it works now. what a bad mistake >.< thank you very much for your hint :)